# Project-specific setting with cmake -> eclipse CDT project generator?

Tags: eclipse, cmake, eclipse-cdt

Generating eclipse project file from a cmake based projects works really good. We no longer need to commit eclipse project files to the repository.

But what is with the project specific settings like 'code style'. In a fixed eclipse project I could save and commit this setting. Is it possible within a cmake based project with generated project files for eclipse?

Answer (score 0):

I do not see a solution to this as cmake completely regenerates the project. That's the reason why I use Makefile projekts with eclipse. I don't see any drawback of this as eclipse can easily trigger the make command.